# nodejs and webstorm ide issue

Tags: node.js, webstorm

Can anyone help me please onto this issue. I have just installed webstorm 8 and trying to create a Node.js-express application and getting following error. It pops a node window but shuts it off within milliseconds. Also if i am trying to create a node.js project manaully, i cannot debug node.js it says "**Process finished with exit code 0**" . Please note if i try to run node **from command prompt it is running fine**.  I am using **windows 8**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try choosing node.exe instead of nodevars.bat as Node executable

Comment: Also tried adding express to global folder using npm install express -g. Did't work either

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your ide. Its working on my case